# Show full screen image on tap flutter (Hero)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-widget, large-image

I have the image shown using [network to local file](https://ghulamustafa.com/2021/05/01/flutter-network-to-local-file-image-audio-video/)

```
Hero(
                           tag: "customWidget",
                           child: Container(
                             width: context.screenWidth / 2,
                             height: context.screenHeight / 4,
                             child: NetworkToLocal(
                               mediaURL: element.payload.uri,
                               mediaType: 'image',
                             ),
                           ),
                         ),
```

I want to add functionality that after tapping on the image I can present this image in fullscreen mode. How it can be done with the hero widget?[image: Image of error]

In the above screenshot, an error occurs highlighting elements when adding

```
                       child: NetworkToLocal(
                            mediaURL: element.payload.uri,
                            mediaType: 'image',
                          ),
```

[image: image of error message]

Answer (score 2):

You use the Hero Animation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(HeroApp());

class HeroApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Transition Demo',
  home: MainScreen(),
 );
}
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Main Screen'),
  ),
  body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
        return DetailScreen();
      }));
    },
    child: Hero(
      tag: 'imageHero',
      child: Image.network(
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
    child: Center(
      child: Hero(
        tag: 'imageHero',
        child: Image.network(
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add a key on hero widget!) In addition, please expand your answer, i.o hero animation on both screens.

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I tried the above example, it doesn't suit my situation. I am not able to use the URL in any other class."mediaURL: element.payload.uri," where in the example above they used network image widget.

Comment: I think you don't understand, how does it works. You can't share completed widget between screens. Hero animation only add animation on widgets that have tags on changing between screens. So hero widget in one screen is not the widget from another screen!

Comment: If you have some cached image, I think it'll not be a problem to you to get it from cache and show it immediately.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. will go through the Hero widget.

Comment: added an error above check edited question, please...

Comment: @sanjeevAV, Replace **mediaURL: element.payload.uri,** to this `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png`

(mediaURL:"your image URL")

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil, It is not working for me. It displays some issues on the screen.

Comment: @sanjeevAV, I first thing tell me why you used ** NetworkToLocal** remove it and use just Hero please try to run my answer

Comment: I used "NetworkToLocal" to avoid caching the image every time. (Using in a chat app)

Comment: No issues with using "NetworkToLocal", Hero widget works well even if  I add  NetworkToLocal. My issue is I can't use  " element.payload.uri, " in any other class.

Comment: Try to declare element as var element ; OR var element = " ";

Comment: declaring the element as the variable doesn't work. It displays an error on the screen "NosuchMethod: the getter 'payload' was called on null."

Comment: Please refer this URL https://www.google.com/amp/s/ghulamustafa.com/2021/05/01/flutter-network-to-local-file-image-audio-video/amp/.   And already told you replace element.payload.uri is replace by your url please check my previous comment